# Operator command in python

Tags: python, printing, operators

I am new to Python and I stumble upon this code:

**def smartypants(n):
for i in range (1, n * (n+1) + 1):
print(i % (n+1) and '*' or '\n', end='')**

I understand that it will print a table of n x n character '*'

However I cannot understand the meaning of what inside print command.

It seems that for i % (n+1) = 1,2.... then it will print '*'
else when i % (n+1) =0 it add '\n' (which is starting new line)

why did it operate this way? would you help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

That function is equal to

```py
def smartypants(n):
    for i in range(1, n * (n + 1) + 1):
        if i % (n + 1):
            print("*", end="")
        else:
            print("\n", end="")
```

Here, `i % (n + 1)` is `True` if the remainder is not 0.
You can observe the behavior of the original command as following.

```sh
>>> 1 and "*" or "\n"
'*'
>>> 0 and "*" or "\n"
'\n'
```